# C++ Mingw32 CreateProcess() failed with error code 2: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++

I am just trying to run a basic program in *notepad++* and *mingw32*. I have attempted multiple different thing but I continue to get.

```
    Current directory: \\THEBOX\Users\jacks_000\Documents
    C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -g "testpgrm"
    CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
    The system cannot find the file specified.

    ================ READY ================
```

When I run the `nppexec` I use the following

```
NPP_SAVE
CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -g "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

I have also tried:

```
NPP_SAVE
CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

I am just using a basic test program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hi";
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if I will have issue running it in the command prompt if I save it this way or if I have done something wrong. I am running *Windows 10* if that is a issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Current directory: \THEBOX\Users\jacks_000\Documents

I think it's because g++ can't access to a SMB share.

Try to compile the file locally.

Comment: going to be honest not super clear on how to do that

Comment: Where is your project exactly? On your computer? Or on another location?

Comment: so I am saving it in the jacks_000\Documents  also i don't know if it is a issue but does it matter that i have two different harddrives for my computer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the location of "C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin\g++.exe". Where it is on your PC, and what is the actual filename, will depend on your installation.

For example, on my machine I have and old version in "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks13_02\MinGW\bin\mingw32-g++.exe", but a newer installation in another folder.

So you need to find the executable name and location of the compiler. You won't need to use the top two lines, just "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks13_02\MinGW\bin\mingw32-g++.exe -g test.c", for example.

I did this and it gave a result of :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks13_02\MinGW\bin\mingw32-g++.exe -g test.c
Process started >>>
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

Comment: i will try this

Comment: Good luck. Shout if you have any questions or get stuck.

Comment: so I realized I was being stupid i wasn't saving the file as a .cpp so it didn't know what it was. Sorry. thank you anyway for the help i tried it your way after i did a fresh start and realized what i did